# MasterViewController BarButton missing after Show Detail Segue is triggered

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I'm still pretty new to Swift and doing little personal projects to aid in my understanding of things.

Right now, I'm using the Master-Detail Application as the template. On the MasterViewController, it is a dynamic TableViewController.

What I'm trying to achieve is when I tap on any of the cells, the MasterViewController will show another list of navigation ( which I have managed to do so using Push segue ), and on the DetailViewController, instead of calling DetailViewController, it is currently calling ContentsViewController which is a ViewController with TabBar ( which I also have got it hooked up using Ctrl Click on the Cell and use Accessory Action -> Show ).

A snippet of the source code that triggers the segue

MasterViewController.swift

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showContentDetailSegue" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            performSegueWithIdentifier ("ContentDetailSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, ContentsViewController has no problem being displayed. However, the BarButton on the top left no longer has the Master BarButton that toggles the MasterViewController.

I've also tried self.presentViewController but it will replace the whole screen which isn't what I have in mind as I wanted to keep the Split View intact.

Where did I go wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Typically, you are not supposed to call "performSegueWithIdentifier" from prepareForSegue(). The latter function is called to set some data on the destination controller.. And when it is called a segue is already in progress. Thus, it looks like you start two segues simultaneously, and this is probably what cases the problem.. Can you rewrite the code as to avoid using prepareForSegue?

Comment: How should I go about doing that then?

Comment: If you share your entire project with me then I'll take a look.

Comment: As I'm pretty new to Swift, how do I share with you with Apple mechanism.

Comment: There is no such mechanism :-) Just upload ZIP file to Dropbox

Comment: Sorry for the delay as I'm cleaning up the code to remove some of things I've tried. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tqypsmsnczykyhc/AABoFM3l4HSgf27x7-HhVHmpa?dl=0

Comment: I am on the road until end of this week, but I promise - next week I'll take a look :)

Comment: That will be great, looking forward to learn from you. In the mean time, I'll continue on my learning journey. Thanks Alexey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found another issue when attempting to click on other tabs whereby the Master on the top left will be amiss until I click on the first tab.

To resolve this, I used what is being suggested in http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/

Include the following codes in the respective swift files that is hooked up with the storyboard xyzViewController

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got a change to look at your code. Btw., today I had to upgrade to Xcode 6.3, so I also had to change your code to Swift 1.2 (not much change).

So, your first goal is to make DetailsViewController a UITabbar. The problem is that project's storyboard does not reflect this intention. Indeed, the second row from SplitVC does not go to Tabbar controller, but it should. Below is the corrected storyboard.

[image: storyboard]

The second problem is in `prepareForSegue`. You are starting a second transition inside the first one, which turns out to be correct. However, you also need to handle the second segue, in order to add `< Back` button:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
       ...
      // start second segue
      performSegueWithIdentifier ("ContentDetailSegue", sender: self)


    } else if segue.identifier == "ContentDetailSegue" {
      // add back button
    }
}
```

Adding back button is a little bit tricky. Since the destination VC is not loaded yet, you *cannot* add back button to its navbar. It simply does not exist yet (it'll be available in that class's `viewDidLoad()` method).

So, we'll save a pointer to back button in a member variable like so:

```
detailsViewController.leftButton = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
```

and install it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let button = leftButton {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
    }
}
```

With these fixes everything works perfectly. You can find the modified code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t75u52h3mufowrs/MDApp_new.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Darn, that's some new concepts that I have to digest =D, which is a happy problem for me. Thanks for the heads up, I'm going to mess around with it and break it and try to incorporate some concepts I have learnt lately like delegate. +1